# Where are sameThat or sameTo phpunit constants?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, assert, assertions

I was ask myself **Why doesn't exist** a method called `sameThat` inside PHPUNIT constants, the next piece code i want test.

```
    $user = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findBy(1,1);
```

Finally this is my test:

```
    $this->userRepository->expects($this->at(0))
               ->method('findBy')
               ->with(
                    $this->callback(function($arg) use ($test) {
                        $part = 'In the first call to findBy method, the first parameter: ';
                            $test->assertThat($arg, $this->logicalAnd(
                                $this->equalTo(1),
                                $this->isType('integer')
                                ), $part .'it was found issues'
                            );//assertThat
                            return true;
                        }),                         
                    )
                ->willReturn($this->user);
```

the above example, As you can see, there is two PHPUNIT constants `equalTo` and `isType`, both I used it, because `equalTo` compairs with `==`, no `===`, so, I change `findBy("1",1)` instead, the test doesn't fail, so, I added `isType` constant to be sure, so, the test fail now.

There is an assert called `assertSame()`, why is there not one equal for PHPUNIT's constants ? for example `sameThat` or `sameTo`.

Comment: `$test->assertSame(1, $arg);`?

Comment: `equalTo()` and `isType()` are [instance methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) (i.e. functions) not [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you mean "constraint" when you write "constant" then you are looking for `identicalTo()`. That is the constraint used by `assertSame()`.